# Pandas drop row with multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

I request your kind assistance in dropping a row from a csv using Pandas using two filters.

```
import pandas as pd

moving = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Salesdata.csv')
df = pd.DataFrame(moving)

df = df[df['Last Name, First Name'] != 'Reid, Mark and Connie' & df['Actual Sale Date'] == 3/8/2015]

df.to_csv('improvedcsv.csv', index=False)
```

My data:

```
Last Name, First Name                      Actual Sale Date
Bugs, Rabbit and Bunny                         12/11/2015
Reid, Mark and Connie                           3/8/2015
Cortese, Robert and Laura                       10/15/2014
Reid, Mark and Connie                           2/28/2015
```

I need to delete the Reid, Mark and Connie with the 3/8/2015. When I run the above drop column snippet the new csv returns NO data, only the column headings. How to fix this, please help Pythoners.

Comment: You want to do it only with pandas ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to put quotation marks around `3/8/2015` and change the logic a bit to filter out all those that are not equal to the condition your are filtering. You also need parentheses around each condition.

```
df[~((df['Last Name, First Name'] == 'Reid, Mark and Connie') & 
    (df['Actual Sale Date'] == '3/8/2015'))]
```

Comment: I made a small edit. You want to return 3 rows correct?

Comment: Yes get rid of the Reid with 3/8/2015.

Comment: Ok. Well this answer should work as it searches for the exact combination and then negates it with `~`

Answer (score 2):

There is an issue with the logic you are using. You are saying to find the dataframe situations where there are no "Reid, Mark and Connie" AND ALSO where the 
sale date is 3/8/2015. Which is none of the rows. What you want is the folowing:

```
df = df[~((df['Last Name, First Name'] == 'Reid, Mark and Connie') and (df['Actual Sale Date'] == 3/8/2015))]
```

Comment: Thanks, but the and would not work in this case, one would have to use & otherwise it would throw out an ambiguous error. I edited it with the & and it still showed all four rows of the data.

Answer (score 2):

In my answer i'll not use `pandas`. I'll do it manually and i assume your input file is called `input_file`:

```
data = (k.rstrip().split() for k in open("input_file", 'r'))
final = [k for k in data if k[-1] != '3/8/2015']

for k in final:
    print(k)
```

Output:

```
['Last', 'Name,', 'First', 'Name', 'Actual', 'Sale', 'Date']
['Bugs,', 'Rabbit', 'and', 'Bunny', '12/11/2015']
['Cortese,', 'Robert', 'and', 'Laura', '10/15/2014']
['Reid,', 'Mark', 'and', 'Connie', '2/28/2015']
```